# QtWidget simple with title and icon only

Tags: c++, qt5, qwidget

i'm trying to modify the QWidget title bar to have a title bar with an icon and title only, (NO close, minimize and maximize button) compatible with any OS...but it shows only title without icon...

my code:

```
setWindowFlags( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint );
```

I tried others flags without a good result...any help? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this example helps: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-windowflags.html

Answer (score 0):

`setWindowIcon()` should do the trick:

```
setWindowIcon(QIcon(QString::fromUtf8("C:\\path\\to\\icon.png")));
```